# Selenium can't find element how to other ways to click on an element

Tags: python, selenium

This website is an intranet, Unable to access from outside,

but I uploaded html, please download and test.

[Download HTML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xqz7FsG48PbMFPqsoXYi3SfMayqhBSxd)

Please check the picture I want to click.

[image]

I tried the following code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '高级查询')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cusAdvancedQuery"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cusAdvancedQuery"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Element not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inside iframe, you need switch first using `.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`:

```
driver.get('url')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'iframe01')))

#element1
driver.find_element_by_id('updateTime1').click()
#element2
driver.find_element_by_id('updateTimeEnd1').click()
#element3
driver.find_element_by_id('cusAdvancedQuery').click()
#element4
driver.find_element_by_id('detailExport').click()
#element5
driver.find_element_by_name('btSelectAll').click()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: hi,I want to enter the date `driver.find_element_by_id('updateTimeEnd1'.send_keys('2019-10-01')` can you help me

Comment: @hakukou You less `)` before `.send_keys`.

Comment: @hakukou I suggest to clear before you put text, try this : `driver.find_element_by_id('updateTimeEnd1').clear()`  
`driver.find_element_by_id('updateTimeEnd1').send_keys('2019-10-01')`

Comment: hi,This error  `Message: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated`